# Using Dygraph in Blazor Hybrid application

Tags: javascript, dygraphs, blazor-hybrid

I'm searching a charting component for a Blazor Hybrid app.
So I wondering if Dygraphs can be used in this context using JSInterop?

One of the feature I'm looking for is the possibility to get the position and the size of the plotting area (not the chart area) because I need to add a scaled background image.

Is this feature available in Dygraphs?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [`getArea()` method](https://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#getArea):

```
getArea()
Get the current graph's area object. Returns: {x, y, w, h}
```